# Catching CertificateExpired Exceptions in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm having trouble catching an CertificateExpiredException in Grails. When I add the exception in the code, I get a "Catch statement parameter type is not a subclass of Throwable." message. If I put a generic "Exception" as a catch parameter, it works.  How I can trap this SSL error and provide a meaningful response for the user?

Here's an example service:

```
class MyService {

    static transactional = false

    String someUrl = 'https://example.com'

    def getThings() {

        def conn
        try {
            conn = someUrl.toURL().openConnection()
        } catch (CertificateExpiredException e) { // doesn't like this
            log.debug e // doesn't work?
            return "SSL error, no results returned."
        }

        if(conn.responseCode == 200){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an import:

```
import java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException

class MyService {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple. I wonder why the IDE didn't pick that up like it does with most issues dealing with imports.